# Spring Testing: Disable logging of, e.g., SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-logback

Before a test is run Spring logs some messages with DEBUG level:

```
16:34:47.177 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.bmw.csc.blocs.cache.TanEventCacheHandlerTest]
16:34:47.186 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
...
```

Is there some way to disable those messages? I have no idea how to configure it as my logger configuration from `logback.xml` and `application.yml` seems to be ignored. The logging format
is also different from the one configured in the `logback.xml`:

```
05.12.2019 16:34:54.390  INFO .catalina.core.StandardService [    Test worker] - Starting service [Tomcat]
05.12.2019 16:34:54.391  INFO e.catalina.core.StandardEngine [    Test worker] - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
```

So the output is not generated using Logback. Looking into `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` I can see that
a `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` is used to create the logger. However, `commons-logging`
seems not to be used (when I list the dependencies).

How can I configure this logger to not log DEBUG messages?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I don't know how to fix that, but I suppose this is related to Gradle, and probably how IntelliJ IDEA launches the gradle test task.